# Appending to mongo query using native driver

Tags: mongodb, go, slice, mongo-go

I have the following code:

```
type SearchReq struct {
    PageSize      int32
    Offset        int32
    Zipcode       string
    PracticeType  []string
    TreatmentType []string
    HasPhotos     bool
    LatLong       GeoLocationInput
}

func buildSearchQuery(searchOptions *database.SearchReq) bson.D {
var filter bson.D

if searchOptions.Zipcode != "" {
    filter = append(filter, bson.E{"zipcode", searchOptions.Zipcode})
}

if len(searchOptions.PracticeType) != 0 {
    filter = append(filter, bson.E{"practicetypes", bson.E{"$all", searchOptions.PracticeType}})
}

if len(searchOptions.TreatmentType) != 0 {
    filter = append(filter, bson.E{"treatments", bson.E{"$all", searchOptions.TreatmentType}})
}

if searchOptions.HasPhotos {
    filter = append(filter, bson.E{"avatarurl", bson.E{"$ne", nil}})
}

return filter
}
```

One of the queries I'm trying to make looks like this:

```
db.providers.find({treatments: {$all: ["botox","not-botox"]}, zipcode: "90210"})
```

The filter prints out this:

```
1st run: [{zipcode 60010} {avatarurl {$ne <nil>}}]
2nd run: [{zipcode 90210} {treatments {$all [botox not-botox]}}]
```

That command line query pulls up results while to Go variant does not. I've tried switching it to a map but to no avail. What am I doing wrong here?

Ideally I'm trying to build a way of adding a set of criteria to one query.

PS. The records from the command linequery

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6001d1aab756f9540e8850ba"), "name" : "Mr. Brandy Emmerich", "accountnumber" : "b0c6ee03ab", "displayname" : "Mr. Brandy Emmerich", "streetaddress" : "92813 Funk Isle", "city" : "New Artville", "statename" : "Oklahoma", "zipcode" : "90210", "websiteurl" : "http://wildermannikolaus.org/robert.wolf", "emailaddress" : "hosea.runte@example.com", "telephonenumber" : "", "hours" : [ { "day" : 0, "open" : ISODate("2021-01-15T17:32:26.383Z"), "close" : ISODate("2021-01-15T17:32:26.383Z") }, { "day" : 1, "open" : ISODate("2021-01-15T17:32:26.383Z"), "close" : ISODate("2021-01-15T17:32:26.383Z") }, { "day" : 2, "open" : ISODate("2021-01-15T17:32:26.383Z"), "close" : ISODate("2021-01-15T17:32:26.383Z") }, { "day" : 3, "open" : ISODate("2021-01-15T17:32:26.383Z"), "close" : ISODate("2021-01-15T17:32:26.383Z") }, { "day" : 4, "open" : ISODate("2021-01-15T17:32:26.383Z"), "close" : ISODate("2021-01-15T17:32:26.383Z") }, { "day" : 5, "open" : ISODate("2021-01-15T17:32:26.383Z"), "close" : ISODate("2021-01-15T17:32:26.383Z") }, { "day" : 6, "open" : ISODate("2021-01-15T17:32:26.383Z"), "close" : ISODate("2021-01-15T17:32:26.383Z") } ], "instagramurl" : "https://instagram.com/ilene.kunde", "twitterurl" : "https://twitter.com/ilene.kunde", "facebookurl" : "https://facebook.com/ilene.kunde", "avatarurl" : "http://wehner.name/nick", "treatments" : [ "botox", "not-botox" ], "practicetypes" : null, "tags" : [ "", "", "", "id", "delectus", "pariatur" ], "metadata" : { "dolorem" : "excepturi", "numquam" : "at" }, "created_at" : ISODate("2021-01-15T17:32:26.383Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6001d1d0701489602c55f82a"), "name" : "Clara McLaughlin", "accountnumber" : "964a3de178", "displayname" : "Clara McLaughlin", "streetaddress" : "8708 Rodolfo Prairie", "city" : "Parisianburgh", "statename" : "West Virginia", "zipcode" : "90210", "websiteurl" : "http://pollich.org/kimberly_rau", "emailaddress" : "emiliano@example.org", "telephonenumber" : "", "hours" : [ { "day" : 0, "open" : ISODate("2021-01-15T17:33:04.526Z"), "close" : ISODate("2021-01-15T17:33:04.526Z") }, { "day" : 1, "open" : ISODate("2021-01-15T17:33:04.526Z"), "close" : ISODate("2021-01-15T17:33:04.526Z") }, { "day" : 2, "open" : ISODate("2021-01-15T17:33:04.526Z"), "close" : ISODate("2021-01-15T17:33:04.526Z") }, { "day" : 3, "open" : ISODate("2021-01-15T17:33:04.526Z"), "close" : ISODate("2021-01-15T17:33:04.526Z") }, { "day" : 4, "open" : ISODate("2021-01-15T17:33:04.526Z"), "close" : ISODate("2021-01-15T17:33:04.526Z") }, { "day" : 5, "open" : ISODate("2021-01-15T17:33:04.526Z"), "close" : ISODate("2021-01-15T17:33:04.526Z") }, { "day" : 6, "open" : ISODate("2021-01-15T17:33:04.526Z"), "close" : ISODate("2021-01-15T17:33:04.526Z") } ], "instagramurl" : "https://instagram.com/presley", "twitterurl" : "https://twitter.com/presley", "facebookurl" : "https://facebook.com/presley", "avatarurl" : "http://baumbach.com/minerva", "treatments" : [ "botox", "not-botox" ], "practicetypes" : null, "tags" : [ "", "", "", "corporis", "eveniet", "velit" ], "metadata" : { "enim" : "nisi" }, "created_at" : ISODate("2021-01-15T17:33:04.526Z") }
```

Comment: Have you printed out your filter to see what it looks like?

Comment: Also, showing the definition of `database.SearchReq` is probably a good idea.

Comment: @super Posted it here.Thanks!

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with the parts you've posted. Maybe the problem lies somewhere else?

Comment: @super well the zipcode query by itself is fine. All of the other queries individually fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is how you add composite filters. If they are not single values, e.g. you're using `$all` or `$ne`, you have to use "full" documents as their values. `bson.E` is not a "full" document, it's just an *element* of a document. A full document is `bson.D` or `bson.M`.

So use this as your filter builder:

```
func buildSearchQuery(searchOptions *database.SearchReq) bson.D {
    var filter bson.D

    if searchOptions.Zipcode != "" {
        filter = append(filter, bson.E{"zipcode", searchOptions.Zipcode})
    }

    if len(searchOptions.PracticeType) != 0 {
        filter = append(filter, bson.E{"practicetypes", bson.D{{"$all", searchOptions.PracticeType}}})
    }

    if len(searchOptions.TreatmentType) != 0 {
        filter = append(filter, bson.E{"treatments", bson.D{{"$all", searchOptions.TreatmentType}}})
    }

    if searchOptions.HasPhotos {
        filter = append(filter, bson.E{"avatarurl", bson.D{{"$ne", nil}}})
    }

    return filter
}
```

Also note that if `searchOptions` is empty the above will return `nil`, which is invalid as a filter. Ensure it's initialized to a non-`nil` empty slice. So instead of

```
var filter bson.D
```

Use

```
filter := bson.D{}
```

Also note that using `bson.M` instead of `bson.D` is simpler:

```
func buildSearchQueryMap(searchOptions *database.SearchReq) bson.M {
    filter := bson.M{}

    if searchOptions.Zipcode != "" {
        filter["zipcode"] = searchOptions.Zipcode
    }

    if len(searchOptions.PracticeType) != 0 {
        filter["practicetypes"] = bson.M{"$all": searchOptions.PracticeType}
    }

    if len(searchOptions.TreatmentType) != 0 {
        filter["treatments"] = bson.M{"$all": searchOptions.TreatmentType}
    }

    if searchOptions.HasPhotos {
        filter["avatarurl"] = bson.M{"$ne": nil}
    }

    return filter
}
```